# Custom view with imageview and text above it

Tags: android

I am trying to create an imageview with text above it. I can do it using imageview and textview but I would like them to be bundled together (in one object as I will be dragging them togther around the screen)

So i created a custom view where I extends Imageview and I set the image using backgroundResourceId . I am not sure how can I add text above the image? Any idea? 
Thanks

Thank you

Comment: Why not just create a `LinearLayout` that would hold both the `Text` and the `Image`. Then you can drag the `LinearLayout` just fine..

Comment: `I can do it using imageview and textview but I would like them to be bundled together` Simply use a **compound drawable** in a TextView. You will also save a View (you get rid of the ImageView). `android:drawableBottom` is your friend: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableBottom. In Java, use `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int, int, int, int).

Comment: Good idea  user3249477..post it as an answer plz :)

Comment: Der Golem, would it accept animationDrawable ? that's the key

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you shoud use a canvas, using the `drawBitmap()` to draw the image and the use `drawText()` function for the text.

Comment: Sure except that that the backgrounddrawable I have is an animation, so doing it that in drawbitmap (by drawing every frame) would be too much